# what's the difference between koa-body vs koa-bodyparser?

Tags: koa

I'm developing node server using koa.js

I have looked for some libraries for body parser.

And there are several kinds of koa body parser.

But I don't know what differences btw them including [koa-body](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body) and [koa-bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser).

Can you explain it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### [New answer]

`koa-body` now support koa version 2. The main difference now remains about file payload parsing. The `koa-bodyparser` cannot parse files, i.e. `multipart/form-data`.

#### [Old answer]

Oh, I got it.

https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki

koa-body supports koa v1, koa-bodyparser supports koa v2.

And former can parse file, but later can't.

Thanks.

Comment: koa-body does support Koa v2, you just have to get the right branch by doing `npm install koa-body@next`. I've edited the wiki to prevent any confusion for other people.

Comment: @DAESONG KIM latter* :D

Comment: @saadq are the two branches merged now? I can only see one repository on the wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Both are  Koa body parser middleware.
I recently faced an issue where I wanted to handle file upload and there comes the main difference.

Koa-body supports -- koa, urlencoded, multipart, json, body, parser, form
and

koa-bodyparser supports -- json, urlencoded, koa, body.

So if you are looking for file uploading features , go ahead with koa-body or koa-better-body (which has more wider scopes)

[Here is detailed reference](https://npmcompare.com/compare/koa-better-body,koa-body,koa-bodyparser)